# Adding new animation to the existing one

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, cakeyframeanimation

I my application i want to move UIImageView from the default position to the point where user has tapped. But if before completing this animation user again taps on other point, that imageView should not start from the original position instead it should start from the point where it had stopped the animation after tapping the new point. How can i do this. Following is my code to move the imageView to the position of the user tap.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
touchedPoint= [touch locationInView:touch.view];

[imageViews.layer removeAllAnimations];

[UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [CATransaction begin];        
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    animationPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [animationPath moveToPoint:imageViews.center];
    [animationPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(touchedPoint.x,touchedPoint.y)];

    pathAnimation.path = animationPath.CGPath;
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [imageViews.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"animatePosition"];
    [CATransaction commit];


}
completion:nil]; //or completion:^(BOOL) finished { your code here for when the animation ended}];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead :

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
} completion:nil];
```

That `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option will make the animation start from the current position of the image. So if you are moving the image with another animation it will all blend in nicely.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but the problem is still same.

Comment: Should i remove [imageview.layer removeallanimation]? and what should be the value for movetopoint?

Comment: Yes , remove `[imageview.layer removeallanimation]`. moveToPoint has any paramater that you want. It's value differs based on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I removed that line but the animation starts from the original point where imageView was added.

Answer (score 0):

1. define a global CGPoint;
2. start a 0.1 seconds step repeating timer along the animation (at user's first tap).
3. at each tick count, read your image's location and set the CGPoint defined above.
4. after the animation starts, when the user taps again, you stop the previous animation, and initiate another one, using the above CGPoint as "moveToPoint".

Invalidate the timer if the animation stops before the user taps to change it's direction.

Comment: I added the timer as you said but in the timer method i get the image view.center as the original center. Imageview is not updating the value.

Comment: You were right. In this case you will have to manage all animations in a timer. Look, alternatively, you have a start point, and an end point (first animation). You find the speed of movement, start the timer, calculate the distance between the 2 points, and using Dist = Speed/Time, you can find the coordinates, so you will have the frame of the moving object.